# How to make all website dead links redirect to particular page via JS?

Tags: javascript, redirect, hyperlink

Here's the issue:

1. Got multiple internal links on the web, still not connected to actual html files.
2. Im working with local files for the time being
3. Wanna make js redirect all of the dead links to one particular page (let's call the file: 404-error-page.html) up until I will finish the rest of html files to make those dead links active again

Purpose: wanna keep user away from seeing 404 blank page and instead show em some temporary page (404-error-page.html)

Sorry if that's messy - 1st time adding a question here.

HTML

```
<html><body><a href="random-link-directing-to-a-non-existing-page"></body></html>
```

JS

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    var $element = $(event.target);
    var link = "404-error-page.html";

    if(result.broken) {
            if(result.http.response && ![undefined, 500].includes(result.http.response.statusCode)) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                document.location.href = link;
            }
     }
    });
```

I've already tried some alterations of this code but it's not working for me.
Firstly, need to make this functional on local files and then ofc online.
Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of server / hosting are you using? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Custom_error_pages - this is generally nothing javascript is supposed to handle but your backend should be able to do that.

Comment: Oh that would be bad news since I need a frontend solution for this. It doesn't have to be js necessarily, sort of automatic selector distinguishing in between of active and dead links would do the thing I think.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `data-dead-link` attribute to all your unfinished link tag as the follow.

```
<a href="./correctEndpoint">Correct Link</a>
<a data-dead-link>Dead Link</a>
<a data-dead-link>Dead Link</a>
```

Before the `</body>` tag insert the follow script

```
var deadLinks = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-dead-link]`)
    
deadLinks.forEach(el => {
    el.href = "404-error-page.html"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea however this solution would have left me with unmarking all of the manual <a data-dead-link> selector tags whenever I would add new finished html file to the html page library. Since Im planning to add many sub pages step by step and with each having multiple dead links it would mean for me neverending re-writing tags on hundreds of links. Any idea on automatic js selector distinguising in between of working and dead links? Thanks mate.